# Groovy identifier with collection

Tags: java, groovy

I've got a very straightforward script that goes through a collection of nodes
and grabs the properties of the node. I thought I could simply reference an 
identifier and get the property but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

The error I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _ for class
```

Here is my script

```
def headerNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(currentNode).find{ _.hasProperty("headerTitle") }
def printTitle = headerNode ? headerNode.getProperty("headerTitle").getString() : ""
```

Comment: Shouldn't `_` be `it`? `.find{ it.hasProperty("headerTitle") }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use 'it' or give it a variable like 'node ->'

```
def headerNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(currentNode).find{ it.hasProperty("headerTitle") }
def printTitle = headerNode ? headerNode.getProperty("headerTitle").getString() : ""
```

or

```
def headerNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(currentNode).find{node ->  node.hasProperty("headerTitle") }
def printTitle = headerNode ? headerNode.getProperty("headerTitle").getString() : ""
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect but why are you using "it" what exactly does that do?

Comment: @DelmonYoung Have a look at *And "it"* [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22). Scroll down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: 'it' is default parameter. If you have a simple case, it is ok to use it, but generally, it is better to specify parameters. If you have nested code, it could get very complex to know which 'it' has what value.